# how to expand variables in tensorflow to a higher dimension?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning

I have defined a weight matrix w,and the matrix is in shape [1, 500], but I 
want to copy w to new variable w1 in shape [100, 1, 500]. in w1, the 100 matrix in shape [1, 500] are all value-equal and they can change its value at the same time when running Back-propagation algorithm, how can I do with that?

Comment: what do you mean that can change its value at the same times? You would like to have 100 shared slices? So update in one slice updates remaining ones?

Comment: I have a output matrix in shape[100, 500, 64] , 100 means the batch_size, I need a weight matrix to make the output data to shape[100, 64], so I need a - [1, 500] weight matrix, since tensorflow only support [100, 1, 500]*[100, 500, 64], w1 represent 100 [1, 500] matrix, the optimizer will optimize w1, I need to store changes on w